# The update order of theano function's update list

Tags: function, updates, theano

Theano function's parameter updates take a list of pair, in which each pair specifys a shared symbolic variable and its new expression after the calculating the function outputs. 
I wonder whether there is any order for the updating procedure. 
The order will matters if two symbolic variable's new expression relies on each other and the updating procedure will use the updated symbolic variable for updating other symbolic variables that rely on it. 
For examples, this list might looks like this,

```py
[(a, b + a), (b, b+ 1)]
```

I have written some function to test this. The result seems to show that it always use the old value in the expression (second term in the pair) to update the symbolic variable in the first term, i.e.,

```py
 a_new = b_old + a_old
 b_new = b_old + 1
```

Is this a defined behavior?

However I found the implementation of momentum [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/craffel/theano-tutorial/blob/master/Theano%20Tutorial.ipynb), 
Here are the codes for generating the update list and param_update symbolic variables

```py
param_update = theano.shared(param.get_value()*0., broadcastable=param.broadcastable)
updates += [(param, param - learning_rate*param_update),
 (param_update, momentum * param_update + (1. - momentum)*T.grad(cost, param))
```

Then in the first iteration, the param will not be updated, because param_updates are all zero. In my understanding, param_update should be updated first, and then use that for updating param.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the update, it always use the previous value (the value before the Theano function call). So you found the right thing.

For momentum, I think it is normal that there is a delay.

Comment: I got confused regarding delay. for Nestrov momentum, I think it supposed be using the current moment velocity to update the weight: v(t) = mu x v(t-1) - eta x gradient(t-1), and then w(t) = w(t-1) + mu x vt - eta x gradient(t-1). so I assume the update should apply a sequential operation?

Comment: You can suppose all is done in 3 steps. First read from all the shared variables. Then all computation are done. Then all writes. Is the shared variables hold the previous values, and you compute the current value of a shared variable X and need the current value of the shared variables for other computation, you should use the *not* shared variables that represent the current x.